# Is there a way to make Mathematica treat a symbol as real?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbols

Is it possible in Mathematica to set the symbols 'a' and 'b' as reals so when I type   'z = a+**I** b;Conjugate[z]' I get 'a-**I** b' and not 'Conjugate[a]-**I** Conjugate[b]'?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ^= or ^:= like this:

```
Im[a] ^:= 0
Conjugate[a] ^:= a
```

Then

```
Conjugate[a + I b]
```

comes out as

```
a - I Conjugate[b]
```

Comment: I came up with a solution that hopefully will do the trick by defining a function: SetReal[a_] := (Conjugate[a] ^:= a; Im[a] ^:= 0; Re[a] ^:= a;) SetAttributes[SetReal, Listable]

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your expression in `ComplexExpand`, like this:

```
ComplexExapnd[Conjugate[z]]
```

check the documentation for `ComplexExpand` for details of why this works.

Comment: Sure, but I was thinking of a more general way of setting a symbol to real. For example, 'Re[a]' and 'Im[a]' would yield 'a' and '0' respectively.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  No.  Mathematica doesn't really do typing like that.  By using `Assumptions` you can coerce some functions into assuming that, say, `a` is a `Real` but that's probably not a general enough approach for you either.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simplify[Conjugate[z], Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

It's not nice but this is the best that I could find

Answer (score -1):

```
Refine[Conjugate[z], {a, b} \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: @NicoHaase  There is really nothing to explain. It is just another way to achieve the same result as the previous answer that used `Simplify`. I suppose I could have added a link to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html). Really don't think it deserved a downvote though.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted your answer, but some explanation would be nice. If it were so simple to write such code as you think it is, there would be no questions about it. But as the OP should be able to learn why your answer solves his problem, you could add some explanation